# Postgres pg_dump catalog attribute missing error

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I’ve been attempting to backup my remote database to my local system, with the following command I found in some other resources :

```
ssh user@host “pg_dump -U username -h localhost -d dbname -C —-column-inserts” \ mybackup.sql
```

The result was :

pg_dump: error: query failed: ERROR: catalog is missing 2 attribute(s) for relid 18141

I’m actually not so much experienced with databases, I searched for the error but none of them made much sense for me to be honest. Anyone can help me with the issue?

Comment: sounds like a corrupt database.  what happens if you omit `-C` or `--column-inserts`?

Answer (score 1):

You have catalog corruption: the `pg_class` entry for relation 18141 has a value of `relnatts` that is two more than the number of rows in `pg_attribute` that have `attrelid` equal to 18141. Just as the error message says: two attributes (= columns) are missing.

Research your conscience what you did to corrupt the catalog. Did you use bad hardware and had crashes? Did you manually manipulate the catalog tables?

You should restore your last good backup.

However, if you want to try to salvage data from that database: If you are extremely lucky, you are dealing with a corrupted index. That could be rebuilt with

```
REINDEX INDEX pg_catalog.pg_attribute_relid_attnum_index;
```

If that works, dump the whole table and restore it to a freshly created PostgreSQL cluster to leave all corruption behind. If that is not enough, hire an expert who can try to salvage some data from the wreck.

Comment: This saved our staging database. All of our stage database was corrupted. We have postgres and timescale plugin on top of it. I ran drop_chunk commands and it corrupted the database. Running above query solved it.

Comment: @MurtazaTahirAli I hope you reported that as a TimescaleDB bug.

Comment: Hey @Laurenz Albe, I did sent an email to timescale support and waiting for their reply. However, I am able to run select query across all database and insert/update only on table which are not partitioned by date. All tables which are partitioned by date are corrupted and any Insert/update statement on them causes postgres to crash and goes to recovery state.